# Any way to speed up Kerio Connect?

Tags: firefox, mac, webmail

My girlfriend is pulling her hair out using Kerio Connect at home for accessing her work emails. Everything seems to operate at a snail's pace. She is using Firefox on a MacBook Pro. I was wondering if there was anything that could make her life easier. For example I remember that it is possible to somehow configure Firefox so that it pre-fetched linked pages so that jumping from one page to another became faster. I also remember that when I tried this out myself years ago it had some unwanted side effects so I undid that option and never tried it again.

Is it possible to switch on this feature for just one specific site?

And would that help with Kerio anyway?

Anything else we could try?

Comment: This question was bumped by a spam answer. I’m voting to close this question because troubleshooting like questions is off-topic in Web Applications SE. Troubleshooting questions related to Firefox for macOS might be on-topic on [apple.se] and [su]. Ask for guidance on their respective Metas and main chatrooms.